# How to properly implement CheckBox in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, game-engine

I want to implement a checkbox in my game for switching volume on and off. I have this so far, but it's not working properly:

```
MusicOnOff.addListener( new InputListener() {
  public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    MusicOnOff.toggle();
  }
  public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    System.out.println("Music: " + MusicOnOff.isChecked());
    return true;
  };
});
```

**EDIT: Ok, never mind. It's toggling with the right mouse button :O. Left is not working though**

Comment: Which class is `MusicOnOff`?

Comment: Did you set the `InputProcessor`?

Comment: MusicOnOff is a CheckBox ||
Yes, I set the InputProcessor

Comment: By "not working properly" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: It won't toggle, it's set to 'true' all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used `Checkbox`, but I'm guessing it's supposed to automatically toggle, so if you do

```
MusicOnOff.toggle();
```

you may actually toggling it twice, giving the feeling that it never toggles.