# How to properly create a mouse Listener for CheckBox in LibGDX Scene2D?

Tags: java, checkbox, libgdx, listener, scene2d

I've been searching online for hours and I'm new to LibGDX game development. 
This link was useful, but I still have not been able make my CheckBox work.
[How to properly implement CheckBox in LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350350/how-to-properly-implement-checkbox-in-libgdx)

I'm using LibGDX and I have to implement two Radio buttons in my menu.

I created two CheckBox and assigned them a style.

```
    check_style = new CheckBox.CheckBoxStyle();
    check_style.font = font;
    check_style.fontColor = new Color(Color.WHITE);
    check_style.checkboxOff = check_skin.getDrawable("checkbox");
    check_style.checkboxOn = check_skin.getDrawable("checkbox2");
    check_style.checked = check_skin.getDrawable("checkbox2");
```

I also added a listener to notice mouse clicks

```
    controls1Check.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            controls1Check.toggle();
            System.out.println("toggle");
        }
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
           System.out.println("Controls1: " + controls1Check.isChecked());
           return true;
        };
    });
```

When I run my program it does not respond to any mouse click. 
How can I resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try ChangeListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are adding your `CheckBox` to a `Stage`? If so, my only idea is that maybe you didn't call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(yourStage);` so even though your CheckBoxes have InputListeners, input is actually not being processed.

Comment: That was it, what a simple mistake haha. Thank you so much!